# Android: SQLite part or full word search not working using SELECT query

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have 10 movie names in SQLite database. I am searching in the database using SearchView and storing result data into ArrayList and then displaying in custom ListView.
The problem is, it works sometimes only. For example, when I search for "the god" or "god" it returns "The Godfather" but when I search for "the shaw" or "shaw" it doesn't return "The Shawshank Redemption". Also, when searching "the" it returns all the movie names starting with "the" like The Godfather, The good, bad and the ugly, the Shawshank redemption etc. I have the below code. Also "Not found" toast is never getting triggered.

SearchActivity.java

```
            searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchBar);
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                    myDB = new DatabaseHelper(SearchActivity.this);

                    data = myDB.searchRecord(query);//Sends search term to database helper which returns all data found according to the search term


                    if (data==null){
                        Toasty.error(SearchActivity.this, "Not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true);
                    }else {  
                        searchResultMethod();//Calling method which stores curser data in arraylist
                    }
            return false;
            }

        private void searchResultMethod() {
            if(data == null)
            {
                Toast toastem = Toasty.warning(SearchActivity.this, "Database is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true);
                toastem.show();
             }else{
                while(data.moveToNext())
                {
                    arrayListTitle.add(data.getString(1));
                    arrayListYear.add(data.getString(2));
                    arrayListRating.add(data.getString(3));
                    arrayListThumb.add(data.getString(4));
                    arrayListUrl.add(data.getString(5));
                 }
        }
         CustomSearchListAdapter customSearchListAdapter = new CustomSearchListAdapter(SearchActivity.this,arrayListTitle, arrayListYear, arrayListRating, arrayListThumb, arrayListUrl);

    searchListView.setAdapter(customSearchListAdapter);
    searchListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent webActivityIntent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, WebViewActivity.class);
                                            webActivityIntent.putExtra("url_list",arrayListUrl);//Sending imdb url to web view activity
                                            webActivityIntent.putExtra("position",i);
                                            startActivity(webActivityIntent);

   }
 });

}
```

searchRecord() method in DatabaseHelper.java

```
public Cursor searchRecord(String searchTerm)
{
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query ="SELECT  *  FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE title LIKE '%" + searchTerm + "%' OR '" + searchTerm + "%' OR '%" + searchTerm + "'";


    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);


    if (c == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (!c.moveToFirst()) {
        c.close();
        return null;
    }

    return c;
}
```

I can not figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you first execute c.moveToFirst(), then data.moveToNext() and then process data. You miss the first row. Change

```
            while(data.moveToNext())
            {
                arrayListTitle.add(data.getString(1));
                arrayListYear.add(data.getString(2));
                arrayListRating.add(data.getString(3));
                arrayListThumb.add(data.getString(4));
                arrayListUrl.add(data.getString(5));
             }
```

to

```
            do 
            {
                arrayListTitle.add(data.getString(1));
                arrayListYear.add(data.getString(2));
                arrayListRating.add(data.getString(3));
                arrayListThumb.add(data.getString(4));
                arrayListUrl.add(data.getString(5));
             }
            while(data.moveToNext())
```

Comment: I was banging my head for two straight days for something so simple. Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure, glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to make you query case insensitive? Like this

```
String query ="SELECT  *  FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE title LIKE '%" + searchTerm + "%' COLLATE NOCASE;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but this should be enough for you,

```
String query ="SELECT  *  FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE title LIKE '%" + searchTerm + "%';
```